# In Python, writing to a text file is not creating a file in the directory I expected

Tags: python

I've been working on a project with Python 3, and I need to store some data on a .txt file. When I run the code, there is no error message. Why doesn't it even seem to create the file?

Here's the code:

```
text = 'Sample text.'
saveFile = open('file.txt','w')
saveFile.write(text)
saveFile.close()
```

I run it from Python IDLE. I'm trying to save the file to my Desktop.

Comment: `saveFile.close()`. or better yet, use a `with` block

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Changing the code to `saveFile.close()` worked for me. Can you recheck that's what you do, because it should work. You could also add one final line to read and print the file for debug: `print(open('file.txt').read())`

Comment: Do you run the code from the command line or do you click to run it? You could add `import os;print(os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()))` to see where the scirpt is running.

Comment: I run it from the Python IDLE.

Comment: You are writing to the current working directory... its just not the directory you think it is. Use the code I posted to write out the folder name. Where do you want it to write? Absolute paths or paths based on your home directory are common targets.

Comment: I'm trying to save it to my Desktop.

Comment: So, pretty much, it is writing to the file, but the file isn't where I want it to be.

Comment: You can create an absolute path to your desktop with `desktop_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Desktop')`. Then, when you want a file on the desktop, do `filepath = os.path.join(desktop_path, 'somefilename.txt')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are writing the file to the current working directory, but that directory isn't the one you want. You can write files relative to your home or desktop directory by generating absolute paths to those directories.

```
import os
home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
desktop_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, 'Desktop')
```

Now you can use it for your files. Note I am using a context manager so I don't have to explicitly close the file:

```
text = 'Sample text.'
with open(os.path.join(desktop_dir, 'file.txt'),'w') as savefile:
    saveFile.write(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to call the `.close()` function rather than simply referencing the method on your last line. Note that the file will be created in the same directory that your .py module is located, so make sure you're looking in the right place for your output.

Comment: Okay, so I found the file that was created, but when I move it to somewhere, like the desktop, and try to write it again, nothing happens.

Comment: You'll have to reference the specific file path to your .txt file if it's no longer in the same directory as the Python module. `C:\Users\User\Desktop\sample.txt` or something like that.

Comment: Okay. I tried that, and I received an error message, "sample.txt not found in directory"...

Comment: Make sure you're using the right directory -- usually you can right click a file and view Properties for an explicit path to the file.

Answer (score -1):

are you sure authority to write file

code better like below

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding:utf-8
'''黄哥Python'''

text = 'Sample text.'

with open('sample.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

Comment: That doesn't help in this case. The file is being written, just not where OP thinks it should.

Answer (score -1):

Does the file exists? Use this code to create it.

```
open('sample.txt', 'a').close()
```

To have that line on the code won't hurt if the file is already created because it opens the file and closes without adding anything. However if it doesn't exists it creates it with the specific encoding that python uses (I think) so you don't have to worry about that. After that, your code should work:

```
text = 'Sample text.'
saveFile = open('file.txt','w')
saveFile.write(text)
saveFile.close()
```

Comment: That won't help. "w" creates the file if it doesn't exist already.

Comment: It doesn't do any good... Files aren't created with a persistent encoding. Any code that reads or writes it needs to know what the encoding is.

Comment: "w" should create it indeed, but not always does. I found some months ago that creating files with "a" removes some of the bugs I was having on my code and I've been using it ever since.